# How to return a method in PartialViewResult in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to return the method in my controller PartialViewResult. Currently, `Load(id)` gives me nothing in `PartialViewResult`.

```
public PartialViewResult Partial(string id)
    {          
       var model = new ClsS();        
       Load(id);
       return PartialView("_Partial", model);     
    }
  public void Load(string id)
   {
      Sdetails sdetails = new Sdetails();
      var model = new ClsS();
      model.Name = sdetails.Namehead(id);
      model.Link = sdetails.LinkName(id);         
   }
```

Comment: Your `Load()` method is creating a new instance of `ClsS` which you never use - its disposed as soon as the method completes. Change it to `private ClsS Load(string id) { .... return model; }` and the use `var model = Load(id);` in the `Partial` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thank you. your comment helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`void` return type doesn't assign anything in partial view because property assignment occurred inside `Load()` method and disposed immediately after method execution completed (changes are not applied to `ClsS` instance inside partial view method). Use `ClsS` class as return type in `Load()` method instead:

```
public ClsS Load(string id)
{
   var sdetails = new Sdetails();
   var model = new ClsS();
   model.Name = sdetails.Namehead(id);
   model.Link = sdetails.LinkName(id); 

   return model; // return modified ClsS instance       
}
```

Then assign `model` by calling `Load` method inside partial view method:

```
public PartialViewResult Partial(string id)
{          
   var model = Load(id);
   return PartialView("_Partial", model);     
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.